# Confusion about sizeof operator

Tags: c++, arrays, macos, sizeof

I am using C++ on Mac OSX Lion and  I have created the following code:

```
float* floatArray = new float[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    floatArray[i] = 0.0 ;
}

std::cout<< "Test size of a float " << sizeof(floatArray[0]) << std::endl;
// The value is 4 byte which is what I would expect.

std::cout<< "Test the size of the whole array" << sizeof(floatArray) <<std::endl;
// the value is 8. I would have expected the value to be 40 bytes.
```

What am I not understanding?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are using c++. Why not use `std::vector` if you need a dynamically allocated array?

Comment: Opps that was a typo. I just threw that together as an example. should have been i like the rest of them.

Comment: @Grizzly I am processing numerical float data(sometimes by the gigs). #1 I'm not convinced a vector is as fast as a float array. #2 I need to index the array(not iterate), #3 I'm using C File to write binary files. C File much faster than iostream and C File allows passing a float array right into the stream operator. #4 I've been told before that even though you can access a vector index using .at() ,it's not proper.

Comment: `vector` is _sometimes_ (very rarely) measurably slower, but `vector` prevents a lot of mistakes, such as the one in your question.  `vector` can index with `[]` just like array, You can send the data to the stream with `&myvector[0]`.  So there goes all of your counterarguments.

Comment: #1 it shouldn't be slower (if used correctly). Always remember the first rule of performance optimizations: Always profile, never assume #2 so? #3 Doesn't matter for using `vector` or `float*` #4 You can index either using `.at()` or  `[]` and there is nothing improper about it. Using `[]` on a `vector` shouldn't be any slower then using it on a pointer (at least in release mode, otherwise there might be bounds checking, but who cares about performance in debug mode). Most importantly `vector` is continous, so you can get a `float*`which can be used like your floatArray using `&vec[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the added info. I'll try those vector techniques in the future. I'm still not clear how I can pass a vector to a C File fwrite() function though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `sizeof(floatArray)` returns the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to.

Answer (score 3):

In your system, size of the pointer in memory is 8 bytes.
Sizeof() operator just looks at the size of that variable in memory. So it prints the size of the float pointer.

You can find more detail here.
[How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

Compare it with this (which actually *is* an array):

```
float floatArray[10] = {0.0};
std::cout<< "sizeof a float " << sizeof(floatArray[0]) << std::endl;
std::cout<< "sizeof the whole array " << sizeof(floatArray) << std::endl;
```

and then, if you need to use dynamically-sized or allocated arrays, consider using std::vector instead.

Comment: Ahh! Thats the difference. Thats a static array. I believe it allocates it's memory from the stack. Its not the same thing, but you just pointed out the answer. sizeof(static array) will return 40 bytes. The data I deal with is so large it would cause a stack overflow. I need my arrays to come from the heap.

Comment: @Miek: Term-wise, that's just an "array". It is not static (it is statically-*sized*); this is a static array: `static int arr[5];` in the same way this is a static float: `static float f;`. Yes, the memory will be allocated on the stack, this is called *automatic storage duration*. So `sizeof(anyarray)` is the size of that array, static or not. What your question has is a *dynamically-allocated array*. It's still an array, but the type you use to access it is just a pointer to the first element. `sizeof` operates on types, so the size information is lost. You should use `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sizeof(floatArray) is actually returning the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.
See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/)

Comment: Yeah. I dont need the size(length) of my array, I need to know the total bytes for file writing. There are other ways to get the same info, but I though I could use sizeof to get it.

Comment: Understood.  But sizeof(floatArray) is returning the size of the pointer (memory address).

You could use:
int length = 10;
int totalMemory = length * sizeof(float);

Comment: @Miek: Or you could use a std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof operator has no knowledge what and how many elements a pointer points to (except when you feed it an **array**, but that's not a pointer, again). So it returns sizeof (float *) - and as you're probably on 64-bit, the size of a pointer is 8 bytes long.